# How to do partial phrase matching with boosting in Solr

Tags: solr, phrase, solr-boost, shingles

We applied boosting and phrase boosting as below:

```
    https://localhost:8983/solr/app_index/select?bq=(Title:"userinput")^20+
    +(Desc:"userinput")^10&pf=(Title:"userinput")^20+(Desc:"userinput")^10
   &q=(bodycontent_t:(userinput))&defType=edismax&tie=0.01
```

Above query is working fine in below cases:

User Input: **Solr Query**

User Input: **Query Analysis**

However, if we type 3 or more terms as below, its not bringing the expected results as mentioned below:

**Expected result is that exact match at first following by partial phrases**

User input: **Solr Query Analysis**

*Expected Results in below order:*

**Solr query analysis** is the best practice

**solr query** is good for analysis

**query analysis** in solr is good

**solr** is key player in search world

**query** your requirements

**analysis** always gives better results

Got some useful links about Shingle filter which may suits this requirement.

```
http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.3.pdf#page=112&zoom=auto,-187,475
```

Is Shingles suits the above requirement? If Yes, please guide how to apply boosting for the shingles or any better way to achieve exact phrase at first then by partial phrases with boosting?

Please guide here. Appreciate your help.

Comment: try with edismax of solr

Comment: already using edismax only

Comment: Can anyone please update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below field type for your field.

```
<fieldType name="string_test" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"> 
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4"
         outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true">
    </analyzer>  
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Please see the analysis page for the text "Solr Analysis Page".

[image: analysis page]

Comment: Thanks much Abhijit. Is there any way to apply boosting for the Shingles? For Ex:  The exact  phrase match should have top boosting following by partial phrase. something like below:  Solr Query Analysis^20 solr query^15 Query Analysis^10 Solr ^5..

Comment: yes. you can try something like defType=edismax&q=Solr Query Analysis&bq=field:value^2.0

Comment: Thanks Abhijit..Will try and let you know..